# Can I hybridize between ARIMA model and exponential smoothing?

Tags: forecasting, arima, stationarity, exponential-smoothing

I have a time series that stabilized at the first difference (d=1) and the model was ARIMA(0.1.0), as I know it is a model that does not really predict.
In this case I relied on hybridization as follows:
[image]

$Z_t$: original data
$Y_t$: smoothing data
$X_t$: output

After applying the method I obtained a good model ARIMA(4.1.0).

Do I consider this method correct and good to adopt?

Comment: Please use capital letters where appropriate.

Comment: OK ,Thank you .

Comment: There is no need for spaces before punctuation marks such as commas, dots and question marks either. They make text harder to read, just as most other things that are ungrammatical.

Comment: I can't speak English well and thanks for your advice .

Comment: About my question, ARIMA(0,1,0) is Random Walk or White noise process ?

Comment: ARIMA(0,1,0) is random walk. ARIMA(0,0,0) is white noise.

Comment: I don't understand the comment that an ARIMA (0,1,0) can not be used to predict. I have never heard that any ARIMA model can not be used to predict and as far as I know random walks are often used to predict in economics. It is not clear to me what you are doing with the ESM, but many ESM can be converted to an equivalent ARIMA. I am not really sure why you would do what you are doing.